# ASP.Net MVC using Donut Caching and Donut Hole caching

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching

Donut Caching and Donut Hole caching is not very clear to me. i read few article on this and those urls are

https://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/mvc/donut-caching-and-donut-hole-caching-with-aspnet-mvc-4
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/chinnasrihari/Asp-Net-mvc-framework-donut-donut-hole-caching/
http://dotnet-helpers.com/mvc/donut-caching-with-asp-net-mvc/

1) when people use Donut Caching then they should use `[DonutOutputCache(Duration=60)]` for action instead of `[OutputCache(Duration=60)]` but if anyone check the links which i have pasted here then must notice people use **OutputCache attribute instead of DonutOutputCache** but this reason not clear to me.

2) if i need to cache partial view then i need to use OutputCache instead of DonutOutputCache or OutputCache actually will use DonutOutputCache internally.

3) if i mention cache location at client side then when another client from different pc visit my same cache page then what will happen? i guess if i maintain cache at client side then for next visitor again db trip will occur and cache the data and store at client side......am i right?

Sorry my English is not good. thanks
so please some one clarify these above 2 points. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) The combination of Outputcache along with the ChildActionOnly attribute is akin to Donut HOLE caching. The hole of the donut is not rerendered, it is served from the cache. By using the ChildActionOnly attribute, then specifying the OutputCache attribute and time, you are saying cache this part of the donut hole on the server for the specified Duration. the donut hole it will serve from the cache. You have to use them both.
Please see a good example: http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/donut-hole-caching-in-asp-net-mvc-by-using-child-actions-and-outputcacheattribute

2) To cache a partial view output, we again use an OutputCache attribute to the action method IN THE CONTROLLER that returns partial view result. Please see http://techfunda.com/howto/275/cache-partial-view-output

3) When using OutputCacheLocation.Client the output cache is located on the browser client where the request originated. Each new visitor that comes in on their first request of the page has that page content cached in their browser.

Comment: 1) My question was when using donut cache then i should use [DonutOutputCache(Duration=60)] instead of [OutputCache(Duration=60)]. using 3rd party but not using donut related attribute. OutputCache is built-in in asp.net mvc and for which i do not need to installed donut related nuget package. please share your opinion.

Comment: tell me when user1 request a page which is cached at client side so when user2 will request the same page then action will fetch data from db. normally we cache to save round trip but in case of client side caching i guess cache will not be used and shared among different user. please share your opinion.  thanks

Comment: With client side caching, the cache is on the client's browser. Two different browsers hit, then yes, the db will be hit. If you cache on server, then you save the hit until time expires.